# Distinguish even/odd pages in header with oneside option

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, double-sided

See the MWE below. How can I achieve (in the standard `book` class) that despite the `oneside` option odd and even pages are distinguished in the header? I would like to have that, also with oneside printing, the header of odd pages displays the chapter while the header of even pages displays the section, just as it would be the case without the oneside option.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[
  a4paper,                                    
  textwidth=16cm,                             
  outer=2cm,
  textheight=45\baselineskip,
  headheight=\baselineskip,
  includehead=true,% Default
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One of Chapter One}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\section{Section Two of Chapter One}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why use oneside? Just set a symmetrical page geometry with the `geometry` package.

Comment: Well, oneside has some (desired) side-effects, for example, `\cleardoublepage` behaves like `\clearpage` ... therefore I use the option. Of course, I could redefine `\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage}`for the oneside version ... but just now I am not sure whether oneside has further consequences I am overlooking ...

Comment: Moreover, even in the oneside version I dont really want a symmetric layout, but the inner margin should be larger so as to allow for binding

Comment: Still I think `twoside` is the way to go.

Comment: OK, with `\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage}` at the beginning of the preamble there are no more blank pages produced by twoside. But how do you solve the problem with changing inner and outer margins? (I edited my question and added my page layout) Ah, I see, it's the `asymmetric` option in the `geometry` package I need.

Comment: This is surprisingly tricky...

Comment: If the `twoside` version doesn't work out, another alternative is to use `\ifthenelse` in the header to distinguish odd and even pages.

Comment: I wrote the ideas into an answer since in the comment enviroment it's too fussy. If somebody comes up with a better solution we can delete my answer later... Do you approve of my answer? Do you think it does what it should do?

Comment: Can you be more concrete about the `ifthenelse` thing, please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another alternative is to use `oneside`, but toggle headers based on the page number, like this:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One of Chapter One}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\section{Section Two of Chapter One}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: What are the pros and cons of both solutions? I mean, is one of the two solutions "cleaner"/more elegant/more robust or whatever than the other? I don't have a feeling for this and I am not sure which answer should be the accepted one ...

Comment: @lpdbw Although I initially suggested `twoside`, I think sticking to `oneside` is cleaner after all. `twoside` just has too many side effects like symmetrical margins on spreads etc.

Comment: OK, so I will accept this answer. Maybe it also fits the original question better since the question actually was how to solve a certain problem under the assumption that `oneside` option is used.

Comment: Could it be that the `ifthen` package has incompatibilies with other packages, e.g. `etoolbox`?

Comment: @lpdbw I can't imagine that, because it's part of the LaTeX base. There might be issues with fragility in certain contexts, though. If you're having problems, there are lots of alternatives. I just wanted to use the "standard method".

Comment: No, I don't have problems. Was just a theoretical question in view of the robustness of the solutions.

Comment: Possibly you could change `R` and `L` in your answer, since in the original question the page was on `RO`. I think that's also pretty much the standard. (Not so important, of course, but then the answer perfectly fits the question.)

Comment: @lpdbw Good point. I also swapped `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` because chapters should come out on odd pages.

Answer (score 11):

Inspired by Stefan Lehmke's comment I found the following solution:

- Use `twoside`.
- Add `\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage}` to avoid that LaTeX forces chapters to start always on even pages (put at the end of the preamble).
- Add the option `asymmetric` in the `geometry` package so that inner and outer marges are not swapped on alternate pages.

---

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  asymmetric,                               
  textwidth=16cm,
  outer=2cm,
  textheight=45\baselineskip,
  headheight=\baselineskip,
  includehead=true,% Default
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}

\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One of Chapter One}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\section{Section Two of Chapter One}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section One of Chapter Two}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\section{Section Two of Chapter Two}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

---